# Is there an alternative to gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Some developers struggle with the complexity and performance of Gradle:

- It can take a long time to build simple app.
- It can takes a long time to build simple change in that app again.
- It can be very difficult to debug build failures.
- It is a large and complex system, with a steep learning curve.
- It requires learning Groovy and a family of DSLs.
- It is not easy to re-use build scripts across large projects.

So, is there an alternative to gradle for android application development?

Looking for a practical, easy to maintain build system which saves developers time.

Comment: My app is very simple and it is almost one of the template apps provided by Android Studio. Simple change takes long time to be built. 20, or 30, or 40 minutes. It is gradle problem. It is not my app problem!

Comment: What is your system specifications?

Comment: win10 64, i5, 8gb Ram

Comment: It is normal that it downloads dependencies at first time. but it is slow each time it builds, although there is no added  dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I think every Android developer asked him/herself that question more than once.

However, Google puts all efforts into improving Gradle builds for Android. Since they are the inventors/owners of Android and a big big company too, I very much doubt, that there is any different building system that comes close to Gradle.

Additionally to Gradle and Google improving the build process with every new version of Gradle and/or Androidstudio, there are many ways to improve the building speed. Easiest one is to allow gradle to use more RAM. 
But you can find a ton of information about that by searching the internet a bit.

Comment: by searching the internet a bit, you can find many many developers complains Gradle slowness.

Comment: That's right. And you can continue doing that and calling for an alternative, or you can try to make the best of what we got, and which is Gradle, whether you like it or not.

Comment: True. The problem is that Google supports Gradle without real alternative!

Comment: @Ridcully i think Gradle is midground between what was and should be, give it 3-5 years at least for the right tool. The problem with Gradle is less to do with technology but with community itself - it's dead, gradle forums are dead, they seem to release new updates but for whom? I can't even do basic pipeline to get data from plugin A task A to plugin B t ask B. There is zero help and spaghetti-google-unindexed-disjointed-official documentation. I believe Gradle Inc. tried to commercialise like Pivotal Software with Spring through consulting and failed dramatically. Waiting for next pun.

Comment: True fact, I never want to use Gradle. Endless build and build is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Android apps with maven or ant, from a shell. You'd have to create your own build scripts. A few years ago, when Google still supported the Eclipse plugin for Android, they used ant as the build tool.

However, it's my experience that gradle is not slower or faster than either maven or ant. There must be something else that slows your build process.